# Custom slider with automatic timed animation and also controls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a news slider that consists of a big slide area (picture and heading) and a second area to the left which contains a simple list of all the slides.

I've managed to get the slider to work so that you can click on one of the list items and this then changes the slide.

However, I'd also like the slider to animate by default through all the slides. I'd like clicking on a list item to override the animation and make the animation loop go to the point in the loop at which the current slide is at. So if the user clicks slide 2, the next slide to be animated to will be slide 3. I'd also like hovering over a slide to pause the animation.

Any ideas how I can achieve the animation/hover part? I am new to jQuery so pretty confused.

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
    var $newsitem = jQuery('.featured-news');

    var $newsitem1 = jQuery('.featured-news.item-1');
    var $newsitem2 = jQuery('.featured-news.item-2');
    var $newsitem3 = jQuery('.featured-news.item-3');

    var $newslistitem1 = jQuery( '.newslist.item-1' );
    var $newslistitem2 = jQuery( '.newslist.item-2' );
    var $newslistitem3 = jQuery( '.newslist.item-3' );

    // click actions

    $newslistitem1.click(function () {
        $newsitem.hide();
        $newsitem1.fadeIn();        
    });

    $newslistitem2.click(function () {
        $newsitem.hide();
        $newsitem2.fadeIn();        
    });

    $newslistitem3.click(function () {
        $newsitem.hide();
        $newsitem3.fadeIn();        
    });

    // timed actions

animate();

function animate() {

    $newsitem1.delay(4000).hide();
    $newsitem2.delay(4000).fadeIn();
    $newsitem2.delay(4000).hide();
    $newsitem3.delay(4000).fadeIn();

}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="newslist item-1">
        News item 1
    </li>
    <li class="newslist item-2">
        News item 2
    </li>
    <li class="newslist item-3">
        News item 3
    </li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li class="featured-news item-1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
         <br>News Story 1
    </li>
    <li class="featured-news item-2" style="display: none">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <br>News Story 2
    </li>
    <li class="featured-news item-3" style="display: none">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <br>News Story 3
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/HdDG6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how I modified your code :

First, setup global variables :

```
var $newsitem = $('.featured-news');

// global variable of the current slide
var current = 0;  

// global variable interval, which will call "nextSlide" func every 3s
var interval = setInterval(nextSlide, 3000);
```

I updated your slide list click function so it become general. You won't need to setup every slide click event now :

```
// attach event to every list item
$('.newslist').click(function () { 

    // clear the interval
    clearInterval(interval); 

    // set it back to reset the timer
    interval = setInterval(nextSlide,3000); 

    // set current slide var to .newslist item index (0, 1, 2,...)
    current = $(this).index(); 

    // hide every shown item
    $newsitem.hide(); 

    // show item which index = current slide index
    $newsitem.eq(current).fadeIn(); 

});
```

Then I created the `nextSlide` function which will increment current before hiding every slides and showing the current one as `$('.newslist').click` function

```
function nextSlide () {

    // if current slide is the last one, go back to the first, else increment
    if (current == $newsitem.length - 1) {
        current = 0;
    } else {
        current++;
    }

    // hide every slides and show the good one
    $newsitem.hide(); 
    $newsitem.eq(current).fadeIn();
}
```

Then I finally set the hover event, which simply clear the timer when mouse enter `.featured-news` and set it back on mouse leave :

```
$('.featured-news').hover(function(ev){
    clearInterval(interval);
}, function(ev){
    interval = setInterval(nextSlide,3000);
});
```

Here is a working fiddle : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CLDa2/)**

This way you can add as many slides as you want without changing the code. You can also bind `nextSlide` function to any button or control (like arrow keys or a "next slide" button).

Hope I helped you :)

Comment: That is fantastic, that's exactly what I needed and so well explained too. Thank you very much for your help! All the best.